# Spring Webflux Threading Model on machine with ONE cpu

Tags: java, multithreading, parallel-processing, spring-webflux

Small question regarding Spring Webflux and project Reactor please.

From the official doc, we can see:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#threading-model

```
Threading Model
What threads should you expect to see on a server running with Spring WebFlux?

On a “vanilla” Spring WebFlux server (for example, no data access nor other optional dependencies), you can expect one thread for the server and several others for request processing (typically as many as the number of CPU cores). Servlet containers, however, may start with more threads (for example, 10 on Tomcat), in support of both servlet (blocking) I/O and servlet 3.1 (non-blocking) I/O usage.
```

What happens if the hardware only has one cpu please?

I have a webapp, which takes a Flux of string as input, and perform a heavy operation on it.

Please note, the heavy operation is non blocking. It has been BlockHound tested, and for sure, does not contain any database, web call IO.

Yet, the computation is heavy, lengthy (but again, non blocking).

What `heavyComputation` does is that it takes the string, performs some in memory decryption,  convert to some objects, check some fields against a BCrypt hash, in memory re encyption.
The `heavyComputation` is very heavy and takes up to 5 second to complete for one string.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/upload-flux", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE, produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> question(@RequestPart("question") Flux<String> stringFlux) {
        return stringFlux.map(oneString -> heavyComputation(oneString));
    }

    private String heavyComputation(String oneString) {
        // heavy and time-consuming in memory decryption
        // heavy and time-consuming conversion to java object
        // heavy and time-consuming validation of fields against hash
        // heavy and time-consuming re encryption 
        // return the re encrypted string
    }
```

I was hoping by using Spring Webflux, I could see some concurrency and asyncs, as the hardware are constrains to 1 cpu only.

Sadly, I observe everything is done on `reactor-http-nio-1` thread, and looks like it is fairly sequential, one first string, heavyComputation which takes 5ish seconds, then the second string, etc.

What am I doing wrong please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

WebFlux is built around the concept that new incoming requests don't spawn new threads (*) like traditional web servers such as servlet containers do. Instead, requests get queued to be processed by a single long-running thread (assuming a single CPU core), similar to how e.g. click events are processed in JavaScript or desktop UI libraries. The benefit of that is that the CPU is freed from much of the overhead associated with managing threads, which is very expensive. It gets to do one job after another instead of creating the illusion that it can do thousands of jobs at once.

This doesn't magically make your CPU go faster, it just makes it waste less time with thread context switching, which is notoriously expensive. Your CPU-bound computations need as many CPU cycles as they need, no matter what thread they run on. Also, with WebFlux, if request processing involves long-running CPU intensive computation, this means that the CPU can't process new requests until it's finished with the current one - unless you explicitly offload it to a worker thread (and wrap it in a Mono). This will however effectively nullify the benefits of the reactive model if those CPU-bound computations are what the application will be busy with most of the time, because the CPU will now yet again have to do thread context switching to alternately assign CPU time to the request processing and the newly spawned worker thread. Or worse yet, it will have to juggle multiple parallel such worker threads as they get spawned through new requests.

You can expect performance gains from WebFlux if your application needs to process a very large number of requests per second, but where individual requests need very few CPU cycles to process and I/O is non-blocking. Your use case seems to be the opposite, so the Reactive model might not actually do anything for you compared to the simpler Servlet model.

If, on the other hand, your use case is such that the CPU-bound work can be parallelized, you *will* need multiple (or at least hyperthreading-enabled) CPU cores to benefit from that. Reactive can't help you there.

(*) Yes, that's an oversimplification, I'm aware of thread pools, I'm just trying to get the point across.

Comment: good answer, and `This doesn't magically make your CPU go faster` is a very good point as many think that reactive is some kind of miracle which it isnt, it solves specific problems as you pointed out.

Comment: Upvoted for the clear writing. I obviously understand the CPU will not suddenly go faster. The same code run on a multi core CPU (even same speed) will increase performance, as there will be multiple reactor cores. This question is regarding the number of cores